# Hi. Why am I getting "NameError: name 'number' is not defined " for this code? Please help me here as I have no idea

Tags: python

```
alphabet=str(input("Enter the alphabet: "))

if "A"==1 and "B"==2 and "C"==3 and "D"==4 and "E"==5 and "F"==6 and "G"==7 and "H"==8 and "I"==9 and "J"==10 and "K"==11 and "L"==12 and "M"==13 and "N"==14 and "O"==15 and "P"==16 and "Q"==17 and "R"==18 and "S"==19 and "T"==20 and "U"==21 and "V"==22 and "W"==23 and "X"==24 and "Y"==25 and "Z"==26:
    number=alphabet

print("The number of the alphabet is",number)
```

Comment: `number` never gets defined because `"A" != 1` or any of the other conditions you have there

Comment: What makes you expect the condition will ever be True?

Comment: Since you have an `if`, then the line `number = alphabet` is not guaranteed to execute. Indeed: `"A"==1` is `False`, so the line will never execute, so `number` is never created.

Comment: the logic would look more like `if alphabet == "a": number = 1`, but there are better ways =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expressions return false so number is not defined. add

```
number = " string is not equal to a number."
```

before the expression.

I think your trying to get a number value for each character? you should be comparing if the value of alphabet equals a given string, then assigning a numerical value to number.
I.E.

```
if alphabet.upper() == "A": number=1
```

Comment: I don't understand how my expressions return false. Can u pls elaborate?

Comment: sure, you are asking if a string that you define, "A", is equal to an int 1. it is not. you also need every other expression to be true.

Comment: I'm not sure what input your expecting for alphabet but you aren't comparing against alphabet in your conditions is the big issue, if I guessed your goal with the code.